# CMD Java output includes file paths under print statements

Tags: java, file, object, cmd, package

[GreetingsClass.java](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xTHLZ.jpg)  [Chapter1.java](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kuZRF.jpg) [Chapter2.java](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BW2Wy.jpg) [Chapter3.java](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CEkY3.jpg)

I have one class, GreetingsClass.java, in package com.CITC1318.course;. Three other classes, Chapter1.java, Chapter2.java, Chapter3.java, in package com.CITC1318.course.Chapters;. GreetingsClass.java imports and creates an object of the other 3 classes. Each constructor in the Chapter classes prints "Hello from Chapter1!", "Hello from Chapter2!", "Hello from Chapter3!" -respectively. 
The output of GreetingsClass.java should read-

$ Greetings, CITC1318!

Hello from Chapter1!

Hello from Chapter2!

Hello from Chapter3!

[But I keep getting this...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2jOxG.jpg)

Comment: Can't help you unless you show us your code. What do your print statements look like?

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29140402/how-do-i-print-my-java-object-without-getting-sometype2f92e0f4

Comment: @Cardinal-ReinstateMonica posted them

Comment: Please paste the code snippet directly into the post instead of the screenshot, see: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303812/7521686

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are constructing your Object you are printing them out, and then after all three Objects are printing out, you are then trying to print the Objects again, but as the Classes do not implement a `toString` method, you will get something like `chapter2@1230123`

Remove the S.O.P from your calling class.

Just instantiate the Objects.